# why Google chart api option give me error named "uncaught syntax error"

Tags: javascript, charts

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

function drawVisualization() {
   // Populate the data table.
    var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Mon',20,28,38,45],
       ['Tues',31,38,55,66],
       ['Wed',50,55,77,80],
       ['Thurs',77,77,66,50],
       ['Fri',68,66,22,15],
    ], true);

    // Draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, 
               {
                 legend:'none', 
                 width:600, 
                 height:400,
                 hAxis.textStyle: {color: 'red', fontName: 'arial', fontSize: 10}
               }
              );
}


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

when I write this code in Google chart api playground and debug the code it give me uncaught syntax error. I am totally new in this api and I was exploring. So can anyone please tell me why this error occur?? The error occur when I add **hAxis.textStyle** option in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that Google docs is a bit funky there; I think that's supposed to be an object:

`hAxis: { textStyle: {color: 'red', fontName: 'arial', fontSize: 10} }`

Comment: that's right, I've just posted an identical answer down there. didn't see yours ;)